# 'Plus' keyword is not working on mysql fulltext searching

Tags: php, mysql, database, full-text-search, match-against

I am using a keyword like '`iphone 6 plus`' or anything including '`plus`' keyword for mysql full text searching on my local database, but its return empty result.

Its only for plus keyword cause when i was using a query like `match('keyword_map') against ('plus' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`.

This query returns empty result.There is a lot of data stored in my database with plus keyword. When i use mysql like search its working.
Please anybody give me solution for that.

Comment: Please, provide your query and structure. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba233b/2 works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plus is mysql reserved keyword. there is also another keyword like

ACCESSIBLE (R)  ACTION  ADD (R)
AFTER   AGAINST AGGREGATE
ALGORITHM   ALL (R) ALTER (R)
ANALYZE (R) AND (R) ANY
AS (R)  ASC (R) ASCII
ASENSITIVE (R)  AT  AUTHORS
AUTOEXTEND_SIZE AUTO_INCREMENT  AVG
AVG_ROW_LENGTH  BACKUP  BEFORE (R)
BEGIN   BETWEEN (R) BIGINT (R)
BINARY (R)  BINLOG  BIT
BLOB (R)    BLOCK   BOOL
BOOLEAN BOTH (R)    BTREE
BY (R)  BYTE    CACHE
CALL (R)    CASCADE (R) CASCADED
CASE (R)    CATALOG_NAME    CHAIN
CHANGE (R)  CHANGED CHAR (R)
CHARACTER (R)   CHARSET CHECK (R)
CHECKSUM    CIPHER  CLASS_ORIGIN
CLIENT  CLOSE   COALESCE
CODE    COLLATE (R) COLLATION
COLUMN (R)  COLUMNS COLUMN_NAME
COMMENT COMMIT  COMMITTED
COMPACT COMPLETION  COMPRESSED
CONCURRENT  CONDITION (R)   CONNECTION
CONSISTENT  CONSTRAINT (R)  CONSTRAINT_CATALOG
CONSTRAINT_NAME CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA   CONTAINS
CONTEXT CONTINUE (R)    CONTRIBUTORS
CONVERT (R) CPU CREATE (R)
CROSS (R)   CUBE    CURRENT_DATE (R)
CURRENT_TIME (R)
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Answer (score 0):

Plus is mysql reserved keyword thats why plus is not working in mysql match against search.